# Unable to call a object changing method

Tags: c++, object, pointers, reference

I have a class which is something like this:

Example.h:

```cpp
class Example{
private:
    int m_x, m_y;

public:
    void print_params() const;
    void modify_params();
};
```

Example.cpp:

```cpp
void Example::print_params() const{
    cout << "x: "<< m_x << ", y: " << m_y << endl;
}

void Example::modify_params(){
    m_x += 1;
    m_y += 1;
}
```

In my main file, I have a `std::set` of `Example` objects. I am then iterating over the set and calling the `modify_params()` function for each `Example` object, so that the private variables of each object is modified. Hence, the code in the main file looks something like:

```cpp
set<Example> example_set;
...
for (auto& example: example_set){
    example.modify_params();
}
```

However, this does not compile, and I get the following error:

> 'this' argument to member function 'modify_params' has type 'const Example', but function is not marked const.

Nowhere in the class declaration have I declared it as `const`, and I can't mark the `modify_params()` function as `const`, the purpose of this function is to modify the private variables. Keep in mind that I have no problem in calling the `print_params()` method as it is marked `const`.

What am I missing here? How can I successfully do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Objects in the `std::set` are constant and are not modifiable.

Comment: Remove the object from the set, modify the object, insert the modified object back into the set.

Comment: ... and for efficiency, if you use C++17 or later, use [`std::set::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) and then modify and move it back into the `set`.

Comment: To see that the culprit is `std::set`,  change the code to use `std::vector<Example> example_set;`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing this out! I had absolutely forgotten that sets are immutable. My code works perfectly when I change the set to a vector!

Comment: @user3775990 A `vector` may work fine for changing objects in place but are you changing them often enough for it to be a performance gain to switch to using `vector`? Extracting a node from a `set`, changing it and reinserting it isn't extremely costly and if you'd rather have a `set` then a `vector`, it's probably what you should do instead.
If you change an element in a sorted `vector` it may result in an unsorted `vector` and any binary searches goes out the window.

Comment: For now, I can work with a vector, as I am not expecting the number of objects in the set/vector to be more than 10 or so. So the loss of switching to a vector shouldn't be much. At a later stage, I may consider working with a set, if needed.

Comment: @user3775990 Ok, but if you need to (binary-) search that `vector` often and efficiently you need to `sort` it after modifying an element (which you don't need when using a `set` and `extract`ing and moving back in after modification).

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I will keep that in mind as I continue to build on my code. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some theoretical background here. You should remember that `std::set` is implemented as a binary tree, so where the element is inserted in the tree depends on its value and on the value of the elements that are already on the tree, this is defined during the insertion of each element.

This binary tree is built so the elements can be retrieved and inserted in sorted order with log(n) performance, changing the value of a single element on the tree would mess up the order.

That's why in this case you should either remove and re-insert the modified element on `std::set` or use another container, such as `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing this out! I had absolutely forgotten that sets are immutable. My code works perfectly when I change the set to a vector!